# QT5 mainwindow slots not being discovered

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator

As per a tutorial I'm following, I'm placing functions that I would like to call in my widget under public: Q_SLOTS in mainwindow.h. When I open mainwindow.ui in design mode, then click edit->edit signals/slots, and left click on a button and drag to the window,I don't see an option to associate the signal I created with one of the functions I specified myself.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

public Q_SLOTS:
    void SendBtnClicked();
    void TypingChanged();
    void LoginClicked();
    void OnMessageReturn();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken... The menu in the screenshot is for connecting an action on your push button directly to a slot of MainWindow. To connect an action on your push button your function, right click the push button, "Go to slot", select the appropriate action and click OK. This will create an appropriately named function. The signals-slots-functions are matched by name.

Comment: Use connect . In cpp , connect(ui->pb_name  , &QPushbutton:: clicked, this ,&Mainwindow:: name of your slot);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect the signal to your slot from there. you should add your slot to that slot list.

For Example, I write this slot in mainwindow.h

```
private slots:
    void  myExampleSlot();
```

that print something.

```
void  MainWindow::myExampleSlot()
{
    qDebug() << "I am here";
}
```

1. press Edit and then add your slot function :

[image]

2. then find this in the slots list and choose it.

[image]

**out put :**

[image]